# Is it impossible to obtain areas under the gamma density function by direct integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, gamma-function

Please help, I am way above my head in the math at this point. I have had *some* calculus and some statistics. I am more than willing to learn, but I am having a huge confusion right now.

In "Mathematical Statistics with Applications" by Wackerly et. al. they state:

"If $\alpha$ is not an integer and 0 < c < d < $\infty$, it is impossible to give a closed-form expression for:

$$ \int_c^d {{y}^{\alpha-1}e^{-y\over \beta}\over \beta^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)}dy  $$

As a result, it is impossible to obtain areas under the gamma density function by direct integration. Tabulated values for integrals like the above are given in *Tables of the Incomplete Gamma Function* (Pearson 1965)."

I have an integral that's similar to this, except messier, and I'm trying to do some basic research on how to solve it. From other answers I found this Wikipedia article "List of integrals of exponential functions"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Integrals_involving_polynomials where it appears that the 3rd formula does show a closed-form solution for the gamma integral, if you let n = $\alpha$ - 1 and c = -1/$\beta$. They say that the solution is:

$$ \int x^ne^{cx}~=~e^{cx}\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{n-i}{n!\over i!c^{n-i+1}x^i}    $$

But (while typing my question lol) I see n must be an integer here, and $\alpha$ is not an integer in general... ($\alpha$ = v/2, where v = degrees of freedom)

1. So if alpha is not an integer then how do we evaluate this integral? I guess in my case I will only need it for multiples of 1/2.
2. Does anyone know a good resource (Calculus textbook) that goes over these type of integrals in detail? How they are derived etc.? Does it have something to do with differential equations, because I noticed a partial derivative in one of the steps from the Wiki article.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you only need it for *positive* multiples of 1/2. Starting with any $\alpha = m/2$ with $m$ odd positive integer, by repeated integration by parts, you can reduce to the case $\alpha = 1/2$.

Comment: @Ted Ok, so it can be done with integration by parts, I remember doing that in college a long time ago. Thank you for the reply Ted.

Comment: By using integration by parts, you can reduce to the case $\alpha = 1/2$. You still have to do the case $\alpha = 1/2$ in some other way, since (as stated in your textbook) the integral doesn't have a closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the denominator is a constant and can be factored out of the integral.

*Mathematica* (actual software) gives:

$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)^{-\alpha} \beta^{-\alpha} \left(\Gamma \left(\alpha,\frac{c}{b}\right)-\Gamma
   \left(\alpha,\frac{d}{\beta}\right)\right)}{\Gamma (\alpha)}$$

which checks out numerically for several choices of $\alpha, \beta, c,$ and $d$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply David. Are you using this https://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/integral-calculator/? Or the actual software.

Comment: @Azimuth I verifiesd Mathematica gives the result above, but Wolfram Alpha times out for an unregistered user (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5By%5E%28a-1%29+E%5E%28-y%2FB%29%2F%28B%5Ea+Gamma%5Ba%5D%29%2C+%7By%2Cc%2Cd%7D%5D).